# Can not delete item that is selected, only deletes the last item added

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to delete the selected item in my RecyclerView, but when I click on my delete Button it just deletes the last item added. And after I delete the last item added I can not delete anymore. What am I missing?

MainActivity

```
public class MainWishActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private RecyclerView wishList;
private androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;

private ImageButton ibaddnewwishlist;

private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;
private TextView NavProfileFirstName, NavProfileLastName;


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference UsersRef, WishListRef;

String currentUserID;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_wish);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Brukere");
    WishListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ønskelister").child(currentUserID);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" Dine Ønskelister");

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainWishActivity.this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    ibaddnewwishlist = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib_addnewwishlist);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    wishList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_wishlist);
    wishList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    wishList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);

    NavProfileImage = (CircleImageView)navView.findViewById(R.id.civ_navprofilepicture);
    NavProfileFirstName = (TextView)navView.findViewById(R.id.tv_headerfirstname);
    NavProfileLastName = (TextView) navView.findViewById(R.id.tv_headerlastname);

    UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("fornavn")){
                    String firstname = dataSnapshot.child("fornavn").getValue().toString();
                    NavProfileFirstName.setText(firstname);
                }

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("etternavn")) {
                    String lastname = dataSnapshot.child("etternavn").getValue().toString();
                    NavProfileLastName.setText(lastname);
                }

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profilbilde")){
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("profilbilde").getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.with(MainWishActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainWishActivity.this, "Profil navn finnes ikke...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            UserMenuSelector(item);
            return false;
        }
    });

    ibaddnewwishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            SendUserToWishListActivity();

        }
    });

    DisplayUsersWishLists();
}

private void DisplayUsersWishLists() {

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WishListClass, WishListViewHolder > firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WishListClass, WishListViewHolder>
                    (
                            WishListClass.class,
                            R.layout.wish_list_single_layout,
                            WishListViewHolder.class,
                            WishListRef


                    ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(WishListViewHolder viewHolder, WishListClass model, final int position) {

                    final String Key = getRef(position).getKey();


                    viewHolder.setFornavn(model.getFornavn());
                    viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                    viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                    viewHolder.setProfilbilde(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfilbilde());

                    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainWishActivity.this, UserWishItemActivity.class);
                            profileIntent.putExtra("Key", Key);
                            startActivity(profileIntent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };


    wishList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


}

public static class WishListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;



    public WishListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setFornavn (String fornavn){

        TextView wishlist_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_firstnamelist);
        wishlist_name.setText(fornavn);

    }

    public void setProfilbilde (Context ctx, String profilbilde){

        CircleImageView image = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.civ_profilepicturelist);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(profilbilde).into(image);

    }

    public void setDate (String date){

        TextView wishlist_date = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_publisheddatelist);
        wishlist_date.setText("    " + date);
    }

    public void setTitle (String title){

        TextView wishlist_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wishlisttitle);
        wishlist_title.setText(title);
    }

}
private void SendUserToWishListActivity(){

    Intent addNewPostIntent = new Intent(MainWishActivity.this, AddWishListActivity.class);
    startActivity(addNewPostIntent);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser == null){
        SendUserToLoginActivity();

    }
    else
    {
        CheckUserExistence();
    }

}

private void CheckUserExistence(){

    final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id)){

                SendUserToUserInfoAcitivity();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private void SendUserToUserInfoAcitivity(){

    Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainWishActivity.this, UserInfoActivity.class);
    setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(setupIntent);
    finish();
}

private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainWishActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
    finish();
}

private void SendUserToFindFriendsActivity(){

    Intent findfriendsIntent = new Intent(MainWishActivity.this, FindFriendsActivity.class);
    findfriendsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(findfriendsIntent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void UserMenuSelector (MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.navbtn_addwishlist:
            SendUserToWishListActivity();
            break;

        case R.id.navbtn_profile:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.navbtn_home:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hjem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.navbtn_friends:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Venner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.navbtn_findfriends:
            SendUserToFindFriendsActivity();
            break;

        case R.id.navbtn_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Instillinger", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.navbtn_logout:
            mAuth.signOut();
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
            break;


    }

}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class UserWishItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tvwishlisttitle;
private EditText etwishitem;
private Button btnaddwishitem;
private RecyclerView wishListitems;


private String currentUserID, databaseUserID;
private String Key, postRandomName;
private DatabaseReference WishListUsersClickRef, UsersRef, WishItemsRef, wishListRef,WishItemsRef1;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_add_wish_item);

    Key = getIntent().getExtras().get("Key").toString();

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Brukere");
    WishItemsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ønsker");
    wishListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ønskelister").child(currentUserID).child(Key);



    tvwishlisttitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_userwishlisttitle);
    etwishitem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_wishitem);
    btnaddwishitem = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_addwishitem);

    btnaddwishitem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CreateWishlist();


        }
    });


    wishListitems = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_wishlistitems);
    wishListitems.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    wishListitems.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


    WishListUsersClickRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ønskelister").child(currentUserID).child(Key);


    WishListUsersClickRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

            String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();

            databaseUserID = dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue().toString();



            tvwishlisttitle.setText(title);

            }


        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    DisplayWishListItems();





}



private void DisplayWishListItems() {

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WishItemClass, WishListItemsViewHolder > firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WishItemClass, WishListItemsViewHolder>
                    (
                            WishItemClass.class,
                            R.layout.wish_list_item_layout,
                            WishListItemsViewHolder.class,
                            WishItemsRef.child(Key)

                    ) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(final WishListItemsViewHolder viewHolder, final WishItemClass model, final int position) {


                    viewHolder.setWishitemname(model.getWishitemname());





                    viewHolder.m1View.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {



                            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserWishItemActivity.this);
                            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.endreslettjobb_dialog, null);

                            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);


                            dialogBuilder.setTitle(model.getWishitemname());

                            final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();

                            final Button btndelete = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

                            btndelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {

                                    WishItemsRef.removeValue();



                                }
                            });





                            return false;



                        }
                    });


                }
            };


    wishListitems.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);



}


public static class WishListItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View m1View;



    public WishListItemsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        m1View = itemView;

    }

    public void setWishitemname (String wishitemname){

        TextView wishitem_name = (TextView) m1View.findViewById(R.id.tv_wishitemname);
        wishitem_name.setText(wishitemname);

    }

    public void setUid (String uid){


    }

}

private void CreateWishlist() {


    postRandomName = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());

    final String wishlist = etwishitem.getText().toString().trim();

    etwishitem.setText("");



    wishListRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {



                HashMap postMap = new HashMap();
                postMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
                postMap.put("wishitemname", wishlist);
                WishItemsRef.child(Key).child(postRandomName).updateChildren(postMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {


                                }


                        });


            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

AddItemActivity

```
private Spinner spwishlisttitle;
private Button btnsavewishlist;

private DatabaseReference UsersRef, wishListRef;


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private String saveCurrentDate, currentUserID, postRandomName;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_wish_list);

    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Brukere");
    wishListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Ønskelister");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    spwishlisttitle = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_wishlisttitle);
    btnsavewishlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_savewishlist);

    btnsavewishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           CreateWishlist();

        }
    });

}

private void CreateWishlist() {

    Calendar calFordDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calFordDate.getTime());

    postRandomName = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());

    final String wishlist = spwishlisttitle.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();



    UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                String userFirstname = dataSnapshot.child("fornavn").getValue().toString();
                String userProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profilbilde").getValue().toString();

                HashMap postMap = new HashMap();
                postMap.put("uid", currentUserID);
                postMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
                postMap.put("title", wishlist);
                postMap.put("profilbilde", userProfileImage);
                postMap.put("fornavn", userFirstname);
                wishListRef.child(currentUserID).child(currentUserID + postRandomName).updateChildren(postMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    SendUserToMainActivity();
                                    Toast.makeText(AddWishListActivity.this, "Ønskeliste opprettet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(AddWishListActivity.this, "Error ocurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                            }
                        });

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}

private void SendUserToMainActivity() {

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(AddWishListActivity.this, MainWishActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
}
```

}

[image]

I have edited my question with my code.
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: where is Key coming from ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén I have edited my post. Key is the random key from another child.

Comment: Yes, but in your code, how are you getting it ?

Comment: I am getting it with this: `Key = getIntent().getExtras().get("Key").toString();` The MainActivity I have before this SecondActivity I add items in another RecyclerView. When I click on one item in that RecyclerView I come to the SecondActivity. And it is in mine SecondActivity I have the Alertdialog where I want to delete the selected item.

Comment: Sorry but we can't help if you don't provide the code where you get your key, since the problem might be when you get the key

Comment: Ok, what code to you want me to post? Since the "Key" is in both my activities? Should I post both?

Comment: The code where you are sending the Key as an extra, and how you are getting the key

Comment: @GastónSaillén I have posted my code now, hope this is helpful. I've tried different things, and manage to make it delete all of my data under "Ønsker" instead of just the one. But I do not want to delete all, only the selected item.

Comment: I am stuck. What am I missing? When I try databaseref.child(Key).child(postRandomName).removeValue(); it deletes everything under "Ønsker". Why is that?

Comment: The only code I need to know is the one you do to generate the key , when you do this `Key = getIntent().getExtras().get("Key").toString();` , you are getting the key from another class, I need to know how that key is beign generated , that might be the root of the problem

Comment: I've added the last activity, this is where I add "Ønskelister" and the `Key` is the Id of the items.